# How to add captcha required only for a particular condition yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I am trying make the captcha field required only when the number of failed login attempts exceed 3 times. For which I have written below code till now.

In LoginForm model I have added the below rules

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ['verifyCode', 'captcha', 'when' => function($model) {
            return $this->checkattempts();
        }],
    ];
 }

  public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
        $this->addLoginAttempt($user->id);
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }
}

 public function checkattempts()
  {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $ip = $this->get_client_ip();
    $data = (new Query())->select('*')  
                ->from('login_attempts')
                ->where(['ip' => $ip])->andWhere(['user_ref_id' => $user->id])
                ->one();
    if($data["attempts"] >=3){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}   

public function addLoginAttempt($uid) {
    $ip = $this->get_client_ip();
   $data = (new Query())->select('*')   
                ->from('login_attempts')
                ->where(['ip' => $ip])->andWhere(['user_ref_id' => $uid])
                ->one();
   if($data)
   {
     $attempts = $data["attempts"]+1; 
        @Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE login_attempts SET attempts=".$attempts." where ip = '$ip' AND user_ref_id=$uid")->execute();
   }
   else {
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT into login_attempts (attempts, user_ref_id, ip) VALUES(1,'$uid', '$ip')")->execute();
   }
 }
```

Here I am validating the password first. If the password is incorrect then I am incrementing the count by 1. This part is working fine. The count is incrementing successfully.

After this I am trying to get the count of failed attempts while validating captcha using the function `checkattempts()`, but it is not working.

Can anyone please tell me where I have made mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does using `$model->checkattempts();` instead of `$this->checkattempts();` in `when` condition changes anything?

Comment: Check your `checkattempts()`, you `return false` when  `$data["attempts"] >=3`, that means captcha is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

```
if (!$model->checkattempts())
//show the captcha
```

Then, in your model rules you'll need something like:

```
['captcha', 'captcha'],
```

In your case, what you can do is use different scenarios depending on the user attempts, and in one scenario (more than X attempts) make the captcha required.

More [documentation about the captcha](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captcha) and about [scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios).

Comment: That is what I added, I have added captcha to verifyCode field and I am trying to make if mandatory only if login attempts exceed 3, which I am getting from database. Here I have used checkattempts to get count. But required is not working. Everytime the form is getting submitted even if number of attempts exceeds 3

Comment: @rjirji take a look at the scenarios link. You should create a scenario where the captcha is required, and one when it's not. Then, when you create the model, use the scenario where the captcha is required according to you checkattempts() method.

Comment: i like the idea to use scenario to handle the problem , +1

Comment: Can you help me with an example